# How do I export a JSON file with morph targets from Maya?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, export, maya

When I export my model from Maya using the Three.js exporter I can see no option to export morph targets. Here is what is shown in the 'Export Selection Options' window,
[image]

When I export my model and open up the JSON file, the contents are as follows,
[image]
I found the following example on Threejs.org - [Morph Targets Human](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human)

But they have exported their JSON file from 3ds Max - [JSON File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/models/skinned/UCS/umich_ucs.js)

Is the only option currently to export from 3ds Max so that morph targets can be included in the JSON file?